# Webscraping - looking to find 'hidden stuff'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

- edit *
  problem has been solved. It was my stupid mistake, not looking far enough. And been focussing on my wrong way of thinking

I'm trying to scrape the prices from following website: [Online webshop](https://www.bol.com/nl/s/?searchtext=last%20of%20us%202&searchContext=media_all&appliedSearchContextId=media_all&suggestFragment=&adjustedSection=&originalSection=&originalSearchContext=&section=main&N=0&defaultSearchContext=media_all)

I can scrape everything, except for the prices. When I do an inspect of the page and look for the prices, the only thing I find is: class="hit-area__link medium--is-hidden"
Which is true :-)
How can I get the price?

btw, I'm using Beautifulsoup (in Python)

Many thanks for helping me out!

Kind regards,
Peter

Comment: problem has been solved. It was my stupid mistake, not looking far enough. And been focussing on my wrong way of thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking a the page, I saw there is a span tag with a class of "promo-price" for each product. Using the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

product_prices = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"promo-price"})
for price in product_prices:
    print(price) #  <span class="promo-price" data-test="price">19 <sup class="promo-price__fraction" data-test="price-fraction">58</sup>
    print(str(price.text).replace('  ', '.').replace('\n', ''))
```

You can obtain the product prices which are put into classes of "price" and "price-fraction" and then strip the new line and replace it the white space with a period

Next time can you copy your code into the question so we know what you have tried :)